# Añadir estilos en JS en un anidación por appendChild()

Tags: javascript, css3, dom

*No tengo idea si alguien puede decirme, el fragmento que dice **Opuesto / Hipotenusa** el cual está almacenado en una variable `txyt` , quiero agregarle a este fragmento un estilo de color pero nose que pueda estar haciendo mal, ya sea el objeto no esté bien definido ya que me genera el siguiente error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined**, si alguien puede explicarme el que estoy escribiendo mal. Gracias *

```js
var txyt = document.createTextNode(" = " + "Opuesto" + " " + "/" + " " + "Hipotenusa");
var valor1 = document.getElementById('Function_Sen').appendChild(txyt);

txyt.style.background = 'red';
valor1.style.background = 'red';
```

```html
<h1 id="Function_Sen">Funcion </h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que crear un elemento para lograr obtener atributos/propiedades. La función `createTextNode` crea un nodo de texto, no cuenta con estas propiedades que necesitas. Primero crea el nodo elemento y luego añádele el contenido.

```js
// primero crea un elemento del DOM
let span = document.createElement("span")
// agregamos el contenido al elemento
span.textContent= " = " + "Opuesto" + " " + "/" + " " + "Hipotenusa";
let valor1 = document.getElementById('Function_Sen').appendChild(span);

span.style.background = 'red';
valor1.style.background = 'red';
```

```html
<h1 id="Function_Sen">Funcion </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

El metodo `createTextNode` por lo que entiendo solo retornar un texto no un elemento. Por eso te sale el error. Lo que debes hacer es crear el texto, crear el elemento y agregar el texto dentro de ese elemento:

```
var texto=document.createTextNode("="+ "Opuesto" + " " + "/" + " " + "Hipotenusa");
//Creamos el elemento usando el metodo 'createElement'
 var txyt=document.createElement("div");
//Y ahora lo colocamos en el elemento
txyt.appendChild(texto);
var valor1 = document.getElementById('Function_Sen');

valor1.appendChild(txyt);

txyt.style.backgroundColor="red";
valor1.style.backgroundColor="red";
```